# Weird character generated in jQuery plugin TableExport.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, character-encoding

I'm using TableExport.js plugin in one page to export a HTML table to excel, it works great so far, but one of the columns have dates in format dd/mm/yyyy, for example 29/09/2016, but the plugin is generating "29ባ"and that's exported to excel, and other characters appear if use **/number**, I have the encoding in the head.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

I don't really have a clue of how to resolve this, I've searched for the caracter ባ (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1263)  but no relation with the /09 part of the date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you save your plugin file and html file as utf8 in your filesystem?

Comment: @Stan html file it's in UTF-8, js is being loaded by cdn
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/3.2.10/js/tableexport.min.js though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know TableExport.js.

But if all you want to do is to import an html table into excel then in excel look in the menu for data --> get external data... import from the internet.

Comment: I have to generate the table myself and the user should be able to export it which is doing so far, but this character is being passed to the excel file, I could just simply use another format like 29-09-2016 which works, but the original date format should be maintained.